# How do I get a server ID from a message in Discord.js?

Tags: node.js, discord.js

I'm sorry for asking a relatively simple question, but I can't seem to find the answer online

Comment: Have you reviewed the documentation...? Both the answers below point straight there, where it’s made very clear how to get this data.

Answer (score 1):

You can get the guild of a message using `someMessage.guild`.
https://discord.js.org/#/docs/main/stable/class/Message?scrollTo=guild

That gives an instance of `guild` which has an `id` property. You can get it using `someMessage.guild.id`
https://discord.js.org/#/docs/main/stable/class/Guild?scrollTo=id

Answer (score 0):

Easy! `<message>.guild.id`

```js
client.on('message', msg => {
msg.channel.send(msg.guild.id);
})
```

Comment: Indeed, you can access the guild id with `msg.guild.id`, but those quotation marks just won't work. The inconsistent usage of semicolons and lack of indentation are both not ideal.

Comment: What quotation marks are you talking about?

Comment: The quotation marks that were present in the original version of your answer.

Comment: Yeah I typed it on my phone before... that's why it was not the right quotation marks